# Thymeleaf <img> inside <div th:text>

Tags: html, css, thymeleaf

I need text wraps around the image.
I have

```
<div th:text="${row.getFeed2().getDescription}">
   <img style="float: left" th:style="${row.getFeed2().getImage() == null} ? 'default' : 'none'" th:src="${row.getFeed2().getImage()}">
</div>
```

But Thymeleaf deletes inner tag `<img>` 
I have explored many options and nothing works.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2):

Move the text inside another tag.  Something like this:

```
<div>
    <span th:text="${row.getFeed2().getDescription}" />
    <img style="float: left" th:style="${row.getFeed2().getImage() == null} ? 'default' : 'none'" th:src="${row.getFeed2().getImage()}">
</div>
```

Edit 2 (without span):

```
<span>
    <th:block th:text="${row.getFeed2().getDescription}" />
    <img style="float: left" th:style="${row.getFeed2().getImage() == null} ? 'default' : 'none'" th:src="${row.getFeed2().getImage()}">
</span>
```

or

```
<span th:inline="text">
    [[${row.getFeed2().getDescription}}]]
    <img style="float: left" th:style="${row.getFeed2().getImage() == null} ? 'default' : 'none'" th:src="${row.getFeed2().getImage()}">
</span>
```

Comment: But I need text to wrap my image.
So there should be a <img> tag inside <'text'> tag
I know this way only
And it's realy hard to do using Thymeleaf

Comment: I'm not sure I understand... can you paste what html you want to output?

Comment: I want

  `<span>
           <img src.../>
 </span>`

Comment: Do any of those edits do what you want?  I guess I don't understand why the extra span tag is a problem.

Comment: I already have to thank you.

But I have tried this ways later.
The fact is that when you use Thymeleaf expression in your tag, like
`<span th:text...>
   <img th:src...>
 </span>`, an inner tag hides | doesn't display | deletes. Thymeleaf doesn't notice inner tag `<img th:src...>`. But I need exactly `<img>` inside `<span>`

Comment: Then the answer is, thymeleaf will never work the way you want.  th:text is defined to overwrite any tags inside of it.  The other two examples I provided render html as `<span>*text content<img /></span>`.

Comment: At least now I have an answer for the customer:)
Thank you.