# Thymeleaf th:text ignores HTML tag

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf

Hello all I have text in a template like this:

```
<p th:text="${title.nameproduct}" >  
    <small>Small subtitle</small>                                                                           
</p>
```

It gives me a result like this:

```
<p>Apple</p>
```

I want to have an output like this:

```
    <p>Apple 
      <small>Subtitle - apple</small>
    </p>
```

Can somebody try to help me with this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43188784/4126893

Answer (score 2):

You may create another tag, for example `<span>` and set the text for this `<span>` and your `<small>` separately.

```
<p>  
    <span th:text="${title.nameproduct}">Apple</span> 
    <small th:text="${subtitle.nameproduct}">Subtitle - apple</small>                                                                           
</p>
```

You may as well set the HTML inside your `<p>` tag with [`th:utext`](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#unescaped-text) ...

```
<p th:utext="${title.html.formatted.content}" >  
    Apple
    <small>Subtitle - apple</small>                                                                           
</p>
```

Inside `title.html.formatted.content` variable you would have pre-formatted HTML.